# VSCode Remote SSH Extension + tmux = -bash: __vsc_prompt_cmd_original: command not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmux, vscode-remote

Maybe about a week or so ago I noticed a weird problem when I use the Remote SSH Extension with tmux. After opening a terminal and starting tmux the following is printed to the console after every command:

`-bash: __vsc_prompt_cmd_original: command not found`

If I check the *Log (Remote Pty Host)* section of the *Output* tab I see the following:

```
[2022-08-19 14:48:23.822] [ptyhost] [warning] Shell integration cannot be enabled for executable "/bin/sh" and args ["-c","wget --version > /dev/null\nif [ $? -eq 0 ]\nthen\n\twget --connect-timeout=7 --tries=1 --dns-timeout=7 -q --header='Metadata:true' -O - http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-03-11\nelse\n\tcurl --version > /dev/null\n\tif [ $? -eq 0 ]\n\tthen\n\t\tcurl --connect-timeout 7 -s --header='Metadata:true' http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-03-11\n\tfi\nfi\nexit 0"]
[2022-08-19 14:48:23.890] [ptyhost] [warning] Shell integration cannot be enabled for executable "/bin/sh" and args ["-c","wget --version > /dev/null\nif [ $? -eq 0 ]\nthen\n\twget --connect-timeout=7 --tries=1 --dns-timeout=7 -q  -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id\nelse\n\tcurl --version > /dev/null\n\tif [ $? -eq 0 ]\n\tthen\n\t\tcurl --connect-timeout 7 -s  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id\n\tfi\nfi\nexit 0"]
[2022-08-19 14:48:23.896] [ptyhost] [warning] Shell integration cannot be enabled for executable "/bin/sh" and args ["-c","wget --version > /dev/null\nif [ $? -eq 0 ]\nthen\n\twget --connect-timeout=7 --tries=1 --dns-timeout=7 -q  -O - http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/id\nelse\n\tcurl --version > /dev/null\n\tif [ $? -eq 0 ]\n\tthen\n\t\tcurl --connect-timeout 7 -s  http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/id\n\tfi\nfi\nexit 0"]
[2022-08-19 14:48:23.900] [ptyhost] [warning] Shell integration cannot be enabled for executable "/bin/sh" and args ["-c","wget --version > /dev/null\nif [ $? -eq 0 ]\nthen\n\twget --connect-timeout=7 --tries=1 --dns-timeout=7 -q --header='Metadata-Flavor:Google' -O - http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id\nelse\n\tcurl --version > /dev/null\n\tif [ $? -eq 0 ]\n\tthen\n\t\tcurl --connect-timeout 7 -s --header='Metadata-Flavor:Google' http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id\n\tfi\nfi\nexit 0"]
[2022-08-19 14:52:08.838] [ptyhost] [warning] Shell integration cannot be enabled for executable "/bin/tmux" and args undefined
```

The last line seems concerning, and if I use the Remote SSH extension for a different host (where tmux works) that line does not appear (leading me to believe the behavior is potentially connected).

Both remote hosts have terminal integration enabled (and disabling terminal integration doesn't seem to do anything). Looking in the settings for VSCode terminal integration, I noticed that tmux is not listed as a supported shell for terminal integration (only bash, pwsh, and zsh are). I also see a warning that a [complex bash PROMPT_COMMAND](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_complex-bash-promptcommand) might also break things (and I have edited my `PS1` to print the github branch I'm on, though that works on the other remote host just fine). The link in the settings (which I've reproduced here) is busted, there's no `#_complex-bash-promptcommand` anchor on that page so that might be a red herring anyway.

Any thoughts? Should I submit a VSCode issue? Am I totally lost here?

Comment: Same problem here, no idea where to start. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: No, and it's still happening. I'm kind of hoping that eventually there will be an update that inadvertently fixes this. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can test the following method.

Using an editor such as nano or vim, Add the line

`unset PROMPT_COMMAND`

to your .bashrc file, and it will take effect on the next session.

To apply the change immediately for the life of the current shell session, type

`unset PROMPT_COMMAND`
in your terminal window.

Comment: Ah, indeed, this seems to do the trick! I didn't realize `$PROMPT_COMMAND` was the thing calling `__vsc_prompt_cmd_original`. In fact, I didn't piece together that `$PROMPT_COMMAND` was a thing at all. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I met also the same thing tips `"-bash: __vsc_prompt_cmd_original: command not found"` in vscode. get rid of the tip to disable the following setting:

```json
{
  "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false
}
```

or UI settings:
[image]